# Java - how to make an image represent which tile to draw in a game?

Tags: java, image, dictionary, 2d, tile

I am trying to figure out how to make my game draw a certain tile in a specific spot using an image to represent each spot. So if a pixel of that image was the color red a specified picture(tile) would be draw in the game, and each pixel that was green stood for a different specified image. I have seen people who make games do this but I dont know how to do it and I dont know the name for it.

If you need more info I can try to explain what I want to do more. Could someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That may actually be slower in the long run.  I would definitely recommend you use a byte array to represent the tiles, i.e. byte[width][height].  It will be faster, easier to manage and easier to extend to something like spriteData[width][height] if a single byte does not supply enough information anymore.

However, if you insist on using an image to store game data, you can use something like the following:

```
File file = new File("mygamedata.jpg");
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);

// Getting pixel color at position x, y (width, height)
int colour =  image.getRGB(x ,y); 
int red    = (colour & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
int green  = (colour & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
int blue   =  colour & 0x000000ff;
System.out.println("Red colour component = " + red);
System.out.println("Green colour component = " + green);
System.out.println("Blue colour component = " + blue);
```

Each component will be in the range (0...255) and you can use that to determine the correct tile, i.e.

```
Graphics2D gfx = (Graphics2D) offScreenImage.getImage();
if (red == 120 && green == 0 && blue == 0) {
  gc.drawImage(tile[whichTileYouWantForRed], x, y, null); // where x and y is the pixel you read.
}
```

Alternatively, you can skip extracting the components altogether, and simply use colour, i.e.

```
if (colour == 0x00ff0000) {
  gc.drawImage(tile[whichTileYouWantForRed], x, y, null); // where x and y is the pixel you read.
}
```

(Which will be slightly faster anyway and actually what you want.)

Comment: alright i still dont get it. Im trying to make my game draw out each tile according to the image(in ur example "mygamedata.jpg").

Comment: is there a way to make the x and y position go up automaticly. so it runs through each position?

Comment: Yes, using a for-loop, but I thought that would be self-evident... What is your experience with Java and/or programming?

Comment: yes i thought about using that. it spit out an error but i figured out why and fixed it. I am generally experienced with Java. I even made a good game of Pong with sounds and a menu. I should be good from here on out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user1144939 You're more than welcome to contact me on here for further assistance.  You seem to be doing something rather interesting!  I'm glad to help...